# How to update Ajax Add To cart Top Cart Link RWD Theme

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, addtocart, rwd-theme

[image]

I am facing some issues while updating cart count with ajax request on the detail page for the RWD theme.

Comment: Not sure that you solved the problem yourself or not. If not then add the codes which you wrote. And if yes then add your experienced answer on the community for all